# why is there a white space in my image inside of a container?

Tags: html, css, image

i have a problem, i have struggled with a white space in my image, this problem does not happen in firefox.

[Here is the problem image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUjAC.jpg)

Here is the code.

HTML:

```
<hr>
<h2>Modos de Mezcla</h2>
<h3>Sobre imágenes (img)</h3>
<article class="card">
  <img src="./assets/tree.jpg" alt="Arbol en una puesta de sol">
</article>
```

CSS:

```
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
hr {
 margin: 0;
}

.card {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  border: thick solid #000;
 }

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Please help me, thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual image?

Comment: try to add "display block" to the img. if not working, probably the image has those white lines. open it with an editor and check it

Answer (score 0):

This because of the global "before & after box-sizing: inherit",

Just change it to **content-box or initial**, it will solve your problem,

I've tried with your code and it was fixed.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
 box-sizing: content-box ;
}
```